# How can I replace a dynamic list of terms with a count using a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Currently this is what I am trying to do. I have a file A and a file B.

File A will have a list of terms like:

- TEXT
- TEXT2

File B will have lots of code in it. This code will contain TEXT and TEXT2.

I need to replace TEXT and TEXT2 with :1 and :2 respectively. I can get this to work when I hard code in the TEXT to be replaced but I really need it to work dynamically.

Below is the code that will work to replace TEXT with :1

```
SET count=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (file_a.txt) do (
    call :subroutine %%A
)

:subroutine
    echo %count%:%1
    set "search=TEXT"
    set "replace=:%count%" 
    set /a count+=1

    set "textFile=file_b.txt"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
 GOTO :eof
```

The line of echo %count%:%1 correctly outputs: 1:TEXT. Why can I not replace the line of:

```
set "search=TEXT"
```

With:

```
set "search=%1"
```

When I do so the output file just has this:

```
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
line:=3:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Load the list of replacement words from file_a
set count=0
for /F %%a in (file_a.txt) do (
   set /A "repl[%%a]=count+=1"
)

rem Do the replacements in file_b
for /F "delims=" %%i in (file_b.txt) do (
   set "line=%%i"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%x in ('set repl[') do (
      set "line=!line:%%x=:%%y!"
   )
   echo(!line!
   endlocal
)
```

Sample input:

```
Currently this is what I am trying to do. I have a file A and a file B.

File A will have a list of terms like:

TEXT
TEXT2

File B will have lots of code in it. This code will contain TEXT and TEXT2.

I need to replace TEXT and TEXT2 with :1 and :2 respectively. I can get this to work when I hard code in the TEXT to be replaced but I really need it to work dynamically.

Below is the code that will work to replace TEXT with :1
```

Output:

```
Currently this is what I am trying to do. I have a file A and a file B.
File A will have a list of terms like:
:1
:2
File B will have lots of code in it. This code will contain :1 and :2.
I need to replace :1 and :2 with :1 and :2 respectively. I can get this to work when I hard code in the :1 to be replaced but I really need it to work dynamically.
Below is the code that will work to replace :1 with :1
```

You just need to complete some minor adjustments...